# Warning at Weld 3 startup with XSD invalid beans.xml for weld:scan tag

Tags: cdi, weld, weld-se, cdi-2.0

I just updated Weld from version 2.4.4 to 3.0.1. I am facing the following error at the application startup and I cannot found a solution. I am using Weld SE.

```
Sep 15, 2017 1:25:12 PM org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlHandler error
WARN: WELD-001208: Error when validating file:/(...)/META-INF/beans.xml@7 against xsd. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'weld:scan'. One of '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":interceptors, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":decorators, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":alternatives, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":scan, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":trim}' is expected.
```

The `beans.xml` contains a Weld specific tag to include some classes in the scan (as only exclusion is supported by the CDI specification).

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <weld:scan>
        <weld:include name="com.company.mypackage"/>
        (...)
    </weld:scan>
</beans>
```

I use the following Maven Weld SE dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Could you tell me what should I do to solve this problem? I have checked for a CDI 2.0 XSD but I haven't found any. Perhaps, the include restriction for the scan is now supported natively by CDI? Or perhaps the Weld XSD has changed?

I have created a ticket on the [bug tracker of Weld](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2428) in case it is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem - I tried to describe in in [JIRA issue for CDI (CDI-717)](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-717).

But to sum it up here, **it's not Weld issue, but rather a problem with CDI 2.0 XSD validation file.**
There was a unintended change where one line was removed.
This line permitted any implementation (e.g. Weld) to add additional elements (from different namespaces) and still pass the XSD validation.

Just for completness, the former XSD file can be seen [here (with the link to missing line)](https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi/blob/master/api/src/main/resources/beans_1_1.xsd#L83).
The new one is then [here](https://github.com/cdi-spec/cdi/blob/master/api/src/main/resources/beans_2_0.xsd).

**BTW you are safe to run your application even with these validation warnings/error.** Weld notices them, but should be able to deal with them and still run your app.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that I've seen your issue before.  I can confirm that `weld:scan` is still supported in Weld 3, but I'm not sure (assuming you're using SE?) it would be supported in your deployment model.

I used this format, and I don't get your error (but I do get weird IDE warnings using your file) so maybe this fixes it?

```xml
<beans xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       version="2.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <weld:scan>
        <weld:include name="org.glassfish.jersey.weld.se.WeldRequestScope"/>
    </weld:scan>
</beans>
```

Note that you should also confirm you're on the right version for Jersey, using CDI 2.0's features - https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/ext/cdi/jersey-weld2-se

Comment: I use SE version with the Jersey plugin. It was working fine without warning on v2. I'll give a try to your version anyway.

Comment: It'd be good to see a full list of your dependencies, as well as how you bootstrap Weld.  CDI 2.0 introduces a full SE mode, so you may not need everything, or there may be other changes you should consider.

Comment: I got the same error with your `beans.xml`. It is not related to the Jersey plugin but to the Weld version, I have updated my question to get this more clear.

Comment: The Weld guys have raised a spec issue, looks like we have removed something.  However, you shouldn't need the `<weld:scan>` stanza any longer.  Can you try without it?

Comment: I need it for the application I am developing to avoid scanning all the fat jar where it is bundled.

Comment: So you're using something like maven shade plugin to build the binary?

Answer (score -1):

The XML is being validated against CDI. You require Weld specific XML, according to https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.0.1.Final/en-US/html/configure.html your `<beans>` should look like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd
          http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans_1_1.xsd">
```

Comment: Adding the schema location to the XML header is not working